# Does $-\tan(x)=\tan(-x)$ for all $x$?

Tags: trigonometry

Just to clarify, does $-\tan(x)=\tan(-x)$ for all $x$?

Comment: Yes, the equality holds for all $x$ in the domain of $\tan$.

Comment: $$-\tan(x)=-\frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{\sin(-x)}{\cos(-x)}=\tan(-x)$$ yep

Comment: $$\text{Yes!}$$

Comment: Is it safe to assume $-\tan(\pi+k\pi)=\tan(\pi+k\pi)$ as the result $\nexists\tan(x)\in\mathbb{R}=\nexists\tan(x)\in\mathbb{R}$, so this *relation* is true even it is not right? `=)`

Answer (score 2):

$$\tan (x) = \frac{\sin (x)}{\cos (x)}$$
$$\tan (-x) = \frac{\sin (-x)}{\cos (-x)}$$
$$\cos (-x) = \cos (x)$$
$$\sin (-x) = -\sin (x)$$
$$\tan (-x) = \frac{-\sin (x)}{\cos (x)}$$
$$= -\frac{\sin (x)}{\cos (x)}$$
$$= -\tan (x)$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Often, when I have questions about things like this, I rewrite everything in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and simplify it using what I know about those.

This also easily follows from the unit circle description of trig functions.

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Putting  }A=0,\text{ in }\tan(A-B)=\frac{\tan A-\tan B}{1+\tan A\cdot\tan B},$$

$$\tan(-B)=\frac{\tan 0-\tan B}{1+\tan 0\cdot\tan B}=-\tan B\text{  as }\tan0=0$$

Answer (score 0):

Recall that cosine is an *even* and sine an *odd* function. This means that $\cos (-x) = \cos x$ and $\sin (-x) = -\sin x$, a fact which you can easily verify by checking their respective graphs. It follows from the basic properties of real numbers that the quotients $\sin x / \cos x$ and $\cos x / \sin x$ are odd.